# WinForms .NET Webcam Issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, video, webcam

Webcam outputs black on the pictureBox1 but the camera works normally. Working on Windows Forms App .NET C# Desktop.

Here are the codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebCamLib;

namespace DIP_Activity_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap imageB, imageA, resultImage;
        private Device selectedDevice;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Device[] devices = DeviceManager.GetAllDevices();
            if (devices.Length > 0)
            {
                selectedDevice = DeviceManager.GetDevice(0);
                selectedDevice.ShowWindow(pictureBox1);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No webcam device found.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WebCamLib
{
    public class DeviceManager
    {
    //  [DllImport("inpout32.dll", EntryPoint="Out32")]
    //  public static extern void Output(int adress, int value);
        
    //  [DllImport("inpout32.dll", EntryPoint="Inp32")]
    //  public static extern int Input(int adress);
        
        [DllImport("avicap32.dll")]
        protected static extern bool capGetDriverDescriptionA(short wDriverIndex,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)]ref String lpszName,
           int cbName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref String lpszVer, int cbVer);

        static ArrayList devices = new ArrayList();

        public static Device[] GetAllDevices()
        {
            String dName = "".PadRight(100);
            String dVersion = "".PadRight(100);

            for (short i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (capGetDriverDescriptionA(i, ref dName, 100, ref dVersion, 100))
                {
                    Device d = new Device(i);
                    d.Name = dName.Trim();
                    d.Version = dVersion.Trim();

                    devices.Add(d);                    
                }
            }

            return (Device[])devices.ToArray(typeof(Device));
        }

        public static Device GetDevice(int deviceIndex)
        {
            return (Device)devices[deviceIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WebCamLib
{
    public class Device
    {
        private const short WM_CAP = 0x400;
        private const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = 0x40a;
        private const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = 0x40b;
        private const int WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY = WM_CAP + 30;
        private const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW = 0x432;
        private const int WM_CAP_SET_OVERLAY = 0x433;
        private const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE = 0x434;
        private const int WM_CAP_SET_SCALE = 0x435;
        private const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
        private const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        private const int WM_CAP_SEQUENCE = WM_CAP + 62;
        private const int WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEAS = WM_CAP + 23;
        private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x20;
        private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
        private const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x40;
        private const int HWND_BOTTOM = 1;
        
        
    //  [DllImport("inpout32.dll", EntryPoint="Out32")]
    //  public static extern void Output(int adress, int value);
        
    //  [DllImport("inpout32.dll", EntryPoint="Inp32")]
    //  public static extern int Input(int adress);
        
        [DllImport("avicap32.dll")]
        protected static extern int capCreateCaptureWindowA([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string lpszWindowName,
            int dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, int hWndParent, int nID);

        [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
        protected static extern int SendMessage(int hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object lParam);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        protected static extern int SetWindowPos(int hwnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        protected static extern bool DestroyWindow(int hwnd);
                
        int index;
        int deviceHandle;
    
        public Device()
        {
            //just a simple constructor
        }
        public Device(int index)
        {
            this.index = index;
        }

        private string _name;
        
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        private string _version;

        public string Version
        {
            get { return _version; }
            set { _version = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// To Initialize the device
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="windowHeight">Height of the Window</param>
        /// <param name="windowWidth">Width of the Window</param>
        /// <param name="handle">The Control Handle to attach the device</param>
        public void Init(int windowHeight, int windowWidth, int handle)
        {
            string deviceIndex = Convert.ToString(this.index);
            deviceHandle = capCreateCaptureWindowA(ref deviceIndex, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, handle, 0);

            if (SendMessage(deviceHandle, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, this.index, 0) > 0)
            {
                SendMessage(deviceHandle, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, -1, 0);
                SendMessage(deviceHandle, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 0x42, 0);
                SendMessage(deviceHandle, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, -1, 0);

                SetWindowPos(deviceHandle, 1, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 6);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows the webcam preview in the control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="windowsControl">Control to attach the webcam preview</param>
        ///                    global::  
        public void ShowWindow(System.Windows.Forms.Control windowsControl )
        {
            Init(windowsControl.Height, windowsControl.Width , windowsControl.Handle.ToInt32());                        
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stop the webcam and destroy the handle
        /// </summary>
        public void Stop()
        {
            SendMessage(deviceHandle, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, this.index, 0);
            DestroyWindow(deviceHandle);
        }
        public void Sendmessage()
        {
            SendMessage(deviceHandle,WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY,0,0);
        }
        
    }
}
```

I sent this code to make my friend test this and it works well for him. What seems to be the problem here?

I've tried:

1. Running as admin
2. Adding Visual Studio to Graphics Preference
3. Also tried on my laptop and still has the same problem

Comment: You mean ur code works on a different pc (your friend's) but not yours??